# How to customize sequelize enum error message?

Tags: node.js, enums, sequelize.js

How can I set this model to return a customized error message like `Jamaica is not a valid input for enum` instead of the standard error message? The solutions I've found like [this](http://www.mshahriarinia.com/home/tools-Business/javascript/node-js/sql-orm/model-definition) only apply to `DATATYPES.STRING` but I need something that works for

This is the Model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Country = sequelize.define("Countries", {
    nameOfCountry: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM(
        "Nigeria",
        "Ethiopia",
      ),
      allowNull: false,
    }),
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add custom error msg and validations like shown in this docs of ***[sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html#per-attribute-validations)***

you have to create custom `sequelize` `validate` function or you can pass arguments

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Country = sequelize.define("Countries", {
    nameOfCountry: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM(
        "Nigeria",
        "Ethiopia",
      ),
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        customValidator(value) {
          if (value !== "Nigeria" || value !== "Ethiopia") {
            throw new Error("error msg you want to write");
          }
        }
      }
    },
});
```

**or**
If you don't want to use custom validate you can use this

```
  validate: {
    isIn: {
      args: [['Nigeria', 'Ethiopia']],
        msg: "Must be Nigeria or Ethiopia"
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks, I have used the second option but it still returns the node error message instead of the one in the validate object. I can't use the first one cos I'm dealing with 54 values. I only put Nigeria and Ehiopia in the question as a preview of the model.

Comment: glad to know that it helped